# Get an object to go toward another object in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to get this missile to **accelerate** its way toward the target and stop/dissapear on impact.

[image]

I cannot get it to work.

What can i do.

Comment: You need to get a direction from one to the other, which is a normalized difference between their coordinates (Vector Math: Subtract → Vector Math: Normalize → Vector Math: Scale)